# How to import geo information in Elasticsearch, Logstash and visualize in Kibana

Tags: logstash, elasticsearch, kibana-4, logstash-configuration

I have some data about flights. I have imported and enrichment them with geo-information by means Logstash configuration file, as follows

```
translate {
        field => "origin_state_abr"
        destination => "[origin_location][location]"
        dictionary_path => "/home/alessandro/Scrivania/dataset/us_dictionary.yaml"
    }
```

But Elasticsearch reads `origin_location.location` as a `String`.

I think that I must re-index data...

Someone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: improved formatting a bit

Comment: Since I can't read your yaml file from here, what does origin_location.location contain?

Comment: Thank you! Origin location.location contains coordinates in the form "lat,lon".